# Simple code confusion about define directive parameter

Tags: c, msp430

I'm trying to learn C to program this small routine on a Texas Instruments MSP430. Could you help me understand the `((unsigned char *) 0x0023)` part?

I'm having issues understanding this middle portion of this Define directive. I've tried looking this up but found nothing on the `((unsigned char *) 0x0023)` portion. This looks like a type cast but its not casting anything.

My major concern is the 0x0023 (decimal 35).  Is this just a unsigned char pointer with 35 bits?

Code:

```
#define P1IFG_ptr ((unsigned char *) 0x0023) unsigned char result;
```

Any help is really appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
((unsigned char *) 0x0023)
```

Is a pointer to **address 0x23**

I think there's a missing newline in your code sample...

On the MSP430 this is the port P1 interrupt flag register:

> Each PxIFGx bit is the interrupt flag for its corresponding I/O pin
>   and is set when the selected input signal edge occurs at the pin. All
>   PxIFGx interrupt flags request an interrupt when their corresponding
>   PxIE bit and the GIE bit are set. Each PxIFG flag must be reset with
>   software. Software can also set each PxIFG flag, providing a way to
>   generate a software initiated interrupt. Bit = 0: No interrupt is
>   pending Bit = 1: An interrupt is pending Only transitions, not static
>   levels, cause interrupts. If any PxIFGx flag becomes set during a Px
>   interrupt service routine, or is set after the RETI instruction of a
>   Px interrupt service routine is executed, the set PxIFGx flag
>   generates another interrupt. This ensures that each transition is
>   acknowledged.

You can read from this register, e.g.:

```
unsigned char result;
result = *P1IFG_ptr;
```

Or write to it, e.g.:

```
*P1IFG_ptr = 1;
```

Comment: Guy Sirton: You were absolutely Right!

    #define P1IFG_ptr = ((Volatile unsigned char *) 0x0023);
    unsigned char result;


Thanks for the very thorough answer!